# "Can´t open socket or connection refused" with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

Im getting a connection refused when I try to send some data to my server app using netcat.

server side:

```
IPAddress ip;
ip = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint ipFinal = new IPEndPoint(ip, 12345);
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Bind(ipFinal);
socket.Listen(100);
Socket handler = socket.Accept(); ------> it stops here......nothing happens
```

Comment: Try using `AddressFamily.InterNetwork` instead, because `ip` might be an IPv4 address.

Comment: You have to show us the client side code also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved, I had to move 1 position in the array, cause the first position points to an IPv6 address.

```
IPAddress ip;
ip = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[1];
IPEndPoint ipFinal = new IPEndPoint(ip, 12345);
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Bind(ipFinal);
socket.Listen(100);
Socket handler = socket.Accept(); //------> it stops here......nothing happens
```

Comment: Please learn to format your code. Just select the code and press Control-K.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with your code, it is functioning perfectly.

The call to Accept() method on the Socket class will block until a connection attempt is made from a client to your TCP port 12345.

"It stops here; nothing happens" is correct and expected behavior, but not accurate description.

What is happening is that your socket is waiting for a client connection.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.accept.aspx

"In blocking mode, Accept blocks until an incoming connection attempt is queued. Once a connection is accepted, the original Socket continues queuing incoming connection requests until you close it."

To test your code, open a telent client (type "telnet" in a command prompt), and enter the command "open localhost 12345". Your code will 'wake up'.

Comment: no it wont.  you need ::1 not local host, becuase he's bound to IPV6 not 4

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a TcpListener instead?

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 12345);
listener.Start();
TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

I've found it much easier to use TcpListner and TcpClient rather than Sockets.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android emulator, whenever it is under Android Studio or Xamarin, its IP is 10.0.2.2

Example: 
http://10.0.2.2:8585/v1/planificacion/planoperativo/cpercodigo/7000012312

Comment: Hay una version de stackoverflow en castellano, usa en esta pagina el ingles. There is a spanish stackoverflow page, in this web please use english.