# Connection refused using C# and Unity3D

Tags: c#, sockets, exception, unity-game-engine

I am trying to open a server connection on my Mac but I keep getting `connection refused`

It fails on the Socket.Connect call and ends up in the exception.

```
    this.socket = new Socket(this.remoteIpAddress.GetAddressFamily(), SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    try {
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(this.remoteIpAddress, this.remotePort);
        this.socket.Connect(ip);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        throw new ApplicationException("Error connecting to broker: " + ex.ToString(), ex);
    }
```

These are the values I am passing for the connect.

```
ip  {192.168.1.65:8080} 
AddressFamily   InterNetwork    System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily
```

when I used `netstat -aux | grep 8080` nothing is returned.  I recently rebooted so the port should be free.

So I am stuck as to why it won't connect.

I looked at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411671/can´t-open-socket-or-connection-refused-with-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411671/can%C2%B4t-open-socket-or-connection-refused-with-net) but it didn't help.

Comment: `when I used netstat -aux | grep 8080 nothing is returned.` -> this means the server is not listening on port 8080. You need a server application to be listening to accept connection on port 8080.

Comment: You have a server and a client and we can't tell which one is the problem. The easiest way to find which one is the problem is to download a third party software then use it to connect to your server and see if it works. Also use it to create a sever then try to connect to it from your code and see if it works. For Windows, I use [Hercules SETUP utility](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.html). I am sure there are similar programs for Mac.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking I am setting up the server, but that may not be correct. Let me try setting up a server on my android and see what happens, @Am_I_Helpful